# still the navigate triggers and upate my url, the method is not calling

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

In my backbone app, i use the `requirejs` to load the js files. as well i need different views, there is no.of links are there in my drop down menu. according to the drop down menu i a adding the `#url` example:

```
http://localhost:85/bino/html/interface-I.html#projectName/project11
```

the navigate method works fine and updating the url, also whenever i copy  and paste this url to any other browser / refresh with current hash state my `router` methods works fine.

But click on link in the drop down menu not working, the method not calling... what would be the reason and how can i fix this..?

my code: main js file (part of code)

```
var extender = _.extend({},backBone.Events);
            var params ={
                boardHolder :$('.boardHolder'),
                column      :3,
                space       :30,
                extender    :extender
            };
            var listApp = new routerer(params);
            backBone.history.start();
            extender.bind("list:selected",function(post){
                listApp.navigate(post.category+'/'+post.filter);
            });
```

my router code :

```
define(["backBone","singleton","listCollection","listView","listViews"],function(Backbone,singleton,listCollection,listView,listViews){
    singleton.router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes:{
            ""                          :"appView",
            "post"                      :"postView",
            "projectName/:id"           :"projectNameView",
            "assignedTo/:id"            :"assignedToView",
            "sortBy/:id"                :"sortByView"
        },
        initialize:function(params){
            this.params = params;
            this.collection = new listCollection;
            console.log('i am called');
        },
        hashView:function(){
            console.log('from hash view');
        },
        appView:function(){
            var that = this;
//          var defaultApp = new listCollection();
            this.collection.fetch({
                success:function(data){
                    new listViews({model:data,params:that.params})
                }
            })
        },
        projectNameView:function(thisView){ // not calling not sync
            console.log('called',thisView); // on click not works
        },
        assignedToView:function(thisView){ // not calling not sync
            console.log(thisView); // on click not works
        },
        sortByView:function(thisView){ // not calling not sync
            console.log(thisView); // on click not works
        }
    });
    return singleton.router;
})
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

navigate only updates the url, you also have to call the route function by setting the trigger option to true. If you'd like to update the URL without creating an entry in the browser's history, also set the replace option to true.

```
listApp.navigate(post.category+'/'+post.filter);
```

would become

```
listApp.navigate(post.category+'/'+post.filter, {trigger: true});
```

Comment: Yes, you are 100% correct. it fixed the issue. thanks very much.